# Merge field in URL not Working Properly

Tags: apex, case

I am creating a form that people can fill out and submit, that creates "CSAT_Survey__c" objects. I am looking to link these objects to Cases, so I have created a master(case) - detail (CSAT_Survey__c) relationship between the two. I have tried to create a URL by concatenating the salesforce baseURL, the CSAT ID and the "caID" Case ID, but I have not been able to get the merge working properly. I was not able to tangibly connect the case record to a CSAT.
Have I missed a step in setting something up on the case object to make this possible? Below is my page and controller.

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="CSAT_Survey__c" extensions="CSATSurveyController">

<title>CSAT Survey</title>
<apex:include pageName="csPageHeader" />   

        <apex:pageMessages />

    <apex:form >
<div class="span10">
<div class="control-groupset">
    <div class="control-groupset-titlebar">Have We Resolved Your Issue?</div>
    <div class="control-groupset-content">

    Were we able to resolve your issue?
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Issue_Resolved__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="No" itemLabel="No"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


<div class="span10">
<div class="control-groupset">
    <div class="control-groupset-titlebar">If we have:</div>
    <div class="control-groupset-content">

    R Question 1
    <div>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Resolved_Q1__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>

    R Question 2
    <div>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Resolved_Q2__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>

    R Question 3
    <div>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Resolved_Q3__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>


    Additional Comments
    <div>
    <apex:inputTextArea rows="5" value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Resolved_Comments__c}" label="Additional Comments" />  
    </div>

    <div>
    <apex:commandLink id="ResolvedSubmit" action="{!save}" styleclass="btn btn btn-primary" style="background-color : Green; background-image:none; color:#002233;">Submit</apex:commandLink>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>



<div class="span10">
<div class="control-groupset">
    <div class="control-groupset-titlebar">If we were not able to today:</div>
    <div class="control-groupset-content">

    UR Question 1
    <div>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Unresolved_Q1__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>

    UR Question 2
    <div>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Unresolved_Q2__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>

    UR Question 3
    <div>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Unresolved_Q3__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
    </div>

     Additional Comments
    <div>
    <apex:inputTextArea rows="5" value="{!CSAT_Survey__c.Unresolved_Comments__c}" label="Additional Comments" />  
    </div>

    <div>
    <apex:commandLink id="UnresolvedSubmit" action="{!save}" styleclass="btn btn btn-primary" style="background-color : Green; background-image:none; color:#002233;">Submit</apex:commandLink>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


</apex:form>        





</apex:page>
```

*Controller Below*

```
public class CSATSurveyController {

public CSAT_Survey__c CSAT {get; set;}

public String templateURL {get; set;}

public String caseId {get; set;}

public String surveyId {get; set;}

public String baseURL;

public CSATSurveyController (ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.CSAT = (CSAT_Survey__c)controller.getRecord();
    surveyId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    caseId   = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caId');
    String urlBase = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    baseURL = urlBase;


}


public void setCaseAndURL(){
   CSAT_Survey__c newSurvey =  [SELECT Id FROM CSAT_Survey__c Where Case__r.Id = :caseId];
    templateURL = baseURL + 'id='+newSurvey.Id +'&caId='+'{!Case.Id}';

}




public pagereference Save() {

    insert CSAT;

    PageReference pg = Page.CSATThankYouTestPage;
    pg.setredirect(true);

    return pg; 

}



}
```

Feel free to let me know if I have started down the wrong path here, but if I am missing something on the right track, any input would go a long way.

Many Thanks,
CP

Comment: where you want to put link on page ?

Comment: I would like it to be in the URL, I do not necessarily want to have that link on the page. When they fill out the survey, I just want it to be available in the related lists for that case (as a related record.

Comment: record will be of CSAT_Survey__c object correct ?

Comment: correct. The form will create a CSAT_Survey__c object, and I want it to be linked to the case it is related to.

Comment: You can mentioned that Case is parent object of CSAT_Survey__c object in that case you can add CSAT_Survey__c  as related list on Case object page layout

Comment: correct, but I thought I needed to establish this record-record relationship in the url. When a user fills out the form, I want it to be linked to teh particular case they were filling it out for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31831/discussion-between-himanshu-and-chris-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the chat discussion if you want to link Case with your CSAT_Survey__c object update your save method as follows

```
public pagereference Save() {

    CSAT.Case__c = caseId;
    upsert CSAT;

    PageReference pg = Page.CSATThankYouTestPage;
    pg.setredirect(true);

    return pg; 

}
```